# Using greenrobot EventBus, if both a base class and a derived class subscribe, what happens?

Tags: java, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using greenrobot EventBus.

If I have a base class B, and a derived class D, and both subscribe to an event E in a function f:

```java
class E {}

class B {
    @Subscribe
    public f(E e) {}
}

class D extends B {
    @Subscribe
    public f(E e) {}
}
```

What happens when a event is sent, and there exists an object of type D?

1. `B.f()` and `D.f()` are both called on the object
2. Only `D.f()` is called
3. `D.f()` is called twice (once for each registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Valid for version 3.1.1**

Assuming you have just registered an instance of `D`:

```
public class Scratch4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventBus.getDefault()
                .register(new D());

        EventBus.getDefault()
                .post(new E());

    }
}
```

And:

```
public class B {
    @Subscribe
    public void f(E e) {
        System.out.println("IN B");
    }
}

public class D extends B {
    @Subscribe
    public void f(E e) {
        System.out.println("IN D");
    }
}
```

Then the `main()` method yields:

```
IN D
```

This is because D overrides the method `void f(E e)` in B.

**Below explains why the method is called once and once only**.

Specifically, when you register a subscriber, the `register` method:

```
public void register(Object subscriber) {
    Class<?> subscriberClass = subscriber.getClass();
    List<SubscriberMethod> subscriberMethods = subscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(subscriberClass);
    synchronized (this) {
        for (SubscriberMethod subscriberMethod : subscriberMethods) {
            subscribe(subscriber, subscriberMethod);
        }
    }
}
```

Registers exactly one method (`D::f`).

Under the hood a `FindState` object is used to capture the lookup.

Subsequently, `findState.checkAdd(method, eventType)` is run in `SubscriberMethodFinder::findUsingReflectionInSingleClass` first of all for `D::f` (we are registering a D, it's at the bottom of the hierarchy), so it returns true -- and this causes the `D::f` method to be added for subscription notification.

It then walks up the hierarchy.

So, the second time it's called (with `B::f`). This returns false - causing it not to be added to the `findState`.

**This rejection** is because `SubscribeMethodFinder::checkAddWithMethodSignature` prohibits making methods candidates for subscription if they are overridden by a child in the current `FindState`:

```
private boolean checkAddWithMethodSignature(Method method, Class<?> eventType) {
    methodKeyBuilder.setLength(0);
    methodKeyBuilder.append(method.getName());
    methodKeyBuilder.append('>').append(eventType.getName());

    String methodKey = methodKeyBuilder.toString();
    Class<?> methodClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    Class<?> methodClassOld = subscriberClassByMethodKey.put(methodKey, methodClass);
    if (methodClassOld == null || methodClassOld.isAssignableFrom(methodClass)) {
        // Only add if not already found in a sub class
        return true;
    } else {
        // Revert the put, old class is further down the class hierarchy
        subscriberClassByMethodKey.put(methodKey, methodClassOld);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Below explains why only the child class' overidden implementation is called**.

This is further enforced by virtue of the fact that we cannot choose which type in the hierarchy method to invoke - if we invoke a method that is overridden, the child-est version will be called. Static and runtime types don't matter.

```
public class Scratch4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        B b = new D();

        Class<B> bClazz = B.class;
        Method bClazzMethod = bClazz.getMethod("f", E.class);

        bClazzMethod.invoke(b, new E());
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
IN D
```

If you were to make `B`:

```
public class B {
    @Subscribe
    public void somethingThatIsNotF(E e) {
        System.out.println("IN B");
    }
}
```

Then the `main()` method would yield:

```
IN D
IN B
```

I'm guessing the order is determined in child-to-parent order (i.e. `D extends B` so `D` comes first).

Comment: Explain why it doesn't get called twice and I'll accept the answer. If you can find documentation to back this up, that would be even better.

Comment: @ymett yup fair enough. Added the _why_ to my answer!